# Upload Multiple Folders Not Working In Chrome Using Resumable.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, file-upload, resumablejs

There is an issue when dragging & dropping multiple folders using resumable.js, on chrome **ONLY**.
It's only upload one of the folders selected. 
I've tested this case on Firefox/Edge and it's working correctly.

Also I notice that if you upload a folder with any files it will the files that are processed before reading the folder entities.

As I think the issue is only on readeing the directory entites cause if I upload two files its working correclty and also this happen **ONLY ON CHROME**.

So Can any one help.

You can check the issue on Github too using the following link:
https://github.com/23/resumable.js/issues/416